# Converting Scheme Functions to Prolog

Tags: prolog, scheme, code-translation

I have two functions I need to convert from Scheme to Prolog for an assignment.

One is called `cycler` and runs a given number through a list of numbers +, -, * in that order until it runs out of the list.

The second, `listsMax`, is given two lists and returns a list of maxes between the two, comparing at each index for the index's max.

Below are the original solutions to my Scheme assignment and my attempts at the Prolog versions. Please verify especially whether my Prolog logic is flawed, although my guess is that I'm syntactically wrong.

```
(define (cycler L N)
    (countCycle L N 0)
)

(define (countCycle L N i)
    (cond ((null? L) N)
          ((= (modulo i 3) 0)
          (countCycle (cdr L) (+ N (car L)) (+ i 1)))
          ((= (modulo i 3) 1)
          (countCycle (cdr L) (- N (car L)) (+ i 1)))
          ((= (modulo i 3) 2)
          (countCycle (cdr L) (* N (car L)) (+ i 1)))
    )
)

cycler([], N, 0).
cycler([X|Y], N, I) :- 0 is mod(I, 3), N is N + X, I is I + 1, cycler([L], N, I).
cycler([X|Y], N, I) :- 1 is mod(I, 3), N is N - X, I is I + 1, cycler([L], N, I).
cycler([X|Y], N, I) :- 2 is mod(I, 3), N is N * X, I is I + 1, cycler([L], N, I).
```

And,

```
(define (listsMax L M)
    (consMax L M '())
)

(define (consMax L M N)
    (cond ((null? L) N)
          (> (car L) (car M)
          ((consMax (cdr L) (cdr M) (cons (car L) N))))
          (else
          ((consMax (cdr L) (cdr M) (cons (car M) N))))
    )
    N
)

listsMax([], [], []).
listsMax([X|W], [Y|Z], [M]) :- X >= Y, listsMax([W], [Z], append([M], X, A)).
listsMax([X|W], [Y|Z], [M]) :- X < Y, listsMax([W], [Z], append([M], Y, A)).

append( [], X, X).
append( [X|Y], Z, [X|W]) :- append( Y, Z, W).
```

Comment: Why do you have backticks around all your functions? If that's for SO formatting, you already have all the code in a code block, so you don't need to mark each function.

Comment: `append/3` wants three lists, so you probably want `append([M], [Y], A)`, except that would be about the same as `A = [M,Y]`. Also, that `A` isn't going to do anything for you because it's a singleton variable (pay close attention to warnings about those, since they almost always signify an error in your thinking). Also, `append/3` is a built-in, there is no need for you to define it yourself.

Comment: Also, `N is N+...` can never work, because variables can only be assigned once in Prolog. You probably want to do something more like `N1 is N + X, I1 is I+1, cycler(Y, N1, I1)`. Also, the `L` there is certainly not what you meant (singleton warning, pay attention to them!) and you tore the X off the list leaving Y remaining, so that's why I think you mean Y there.

Comment: One final remark, it's very bad style in Scheme to have close parens on their own lines. If you're not sure how to format Scheme or Lisp code, load it in Emacs and let Emacs format it for you to show you how it should look. (Your Prolog is formatted nicely OTOH!)

Comment: Don't try "assignments" (`N is N + X, I is I + 1`) – stay closer to the Scheme code.